# Any idea what this awesome font is?

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know what this font is? 
I have already tried using whatthefont

Var1. Originally posted by topic starter.

[image]

Var2.

[image]

The are differences between the images, however they may be result of scaling or other image manipulations.

Comment: @Ilan I don't think your edit is the same font...unless the original version was compressed vertically. Note the geometry of the 'G'.

Comment: @DA01 you're right. there are diffs, but they look like parts of the ORATOR family. edited

Comment: The difference is one is lower-case (Orator is a small-cap-only font) and one is upper-case. It would be good to add a link to the original.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, cool catch!

Comment: Yes, good catch! Didn't occur to me that they could be small caps. (I much prefer the geometry of the small caps letters).

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [Linotype Orator](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/orator/orator/), [Adobe Orator Medium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/orator/) or some other type of [Orator](http://fontzone.net/font-details/oratorstd)?

Comment: Hi there - Seems like you nailed it. Would be good, though, if you added some screenshots of those fonts; for further reference and ease of use..

Comment: Yes. Now that you mention it, it's a golfball-typewriter font. I was racking my brains trying to remember where I'd seen it before...